# .Copy Not Executing Randomly

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script to look at a list of orders and grab the order numbers from a selection, remove any duplicates, and copy it to the clipboard. However, I am getting an error about 75% of the time and have determined it is due to the Range.Copy line not working.

I have added an application.wait line which works around the issue however the code is pretty slow now. I'm wondering if there is a faster solution.

```
'Copies unique values in selection (one column only)
    Selection.Copy
    '(copies the list of numbers I've already selected earlier in the code)
    Set TEMPWB = Workbooks.Add
    Set TEMPWS = TEMPWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    TEMPWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    With TEMPWS
        .Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        LASTROW = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '.Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        '^--the delay I added, v--the copy code that isn't working
        .Range("A1:A" & LASTROW).Copy
    End With
    TEMPWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Wrap up
    CBDATA.GetFromClipboard
    'CBDATA is Dimmed as a New MSForms.DataObject
    CBCONTENTS = CBDATA.GetText
```

When I run the script without the delay I usually get this message: "Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)': DataObject:GetFromClipboard OpenClipboard Failed"
I have determined this is a result of the range("A1:A" & LASTROW) failing to copy. If there is a solution to this that doesn't slow the code down so much I'd really love to know.

EDIT: The numbers need to be available in the clipboard for pasting outside of Excel, so I can't cut the clipboard out of the process.

Comment: Have you done a check on `LASTROW` to ensure it is >= 1?  Have you verified correct values when manually stepping through (F8)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have confirmed that LASTROW is always >=1 and I have stepped through but never encounter the issue when I step through manually

Comment: You need to qualify the Rows.Count to read `.Rows.Count` and that should help, but may not resolve the issue.  When you manually step through, you are verifying you're on the correct sheet, etc.

Comment: Where do you end up writing `CBCONTENTS`? Is it in another worksheet?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon CBCONTENTS is written at the beginning of the code (not included here sorry) as a string.

Comment: @Cyril I'm not having an issue with rows.count but thanks anyways!

Comment: That wasn't the question. I'm asking what you do with the contents once you retrieved it from the clipboard. There's a non-zero chance you're massively over-complicating things, depending on where `CBCONTENTS` needs to end up. Clipboard data being read in-process is telling me the final destination of the data is known to this VBA code, and if that's the case then there's very probably no need for `CBDATA` to exist at all.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon OH I see. It's being placed into a msgbox to confirm to the user which numbers were copied.

Comment: For example `Dim contents As Variant` and then `contents = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A" & LASTROW))` would have `contents` hold a one-dimensional variant array containing all the values; from there you could `Join` the array (using a delimiter, say, `vbNewLine`) into a `String` that can be shown in a `MsgBox`, and the array itself is held in memory, ready to be used wherever it's needed - and the clipboard never needs to get involved. OTOH if the data needs to be pasted *outside of the EXCEL.EXE host process*, it's a different story... but we can't *know* that just from the OP.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's my bad I should have mentioned it DOES need to be pasted outside excel in the OP. I'll edit that. However, that is very informative. Thank you!

Comment: See if adding `DoEvents` just after the `.Copy` call helps.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon You're a god. Worked like a charm, super fast. Thank you!!!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Could you add that as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `DoEvents` after the call to `Range.Copy` - presumably there's some kind of a race condition going on in the message pump; `DoEvents` will let any pending messages be processed before the next statement is executed.